# Laravel 5.5 - auth->attempt() always returns false

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.5

I know there's many topics about attempt() which always returns false but I don't know where my problem is. I try to connect my players, so here is the files.

**Information** : I use only email and password to login

**Player.php** - There's the setPasswordAttribute() function that I saw as a solution on many topics.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as BasicAuthenticatible;

class Player extends Model implements Authenticatable{

use BasicAuthenticatible;

public $timestamps = false;
protected $table = 'players';

protected $fillable = [
    'pseudonyme',
    'email',
    'password',
];

protected $hidden = ['password'];

}
```

**ConnexionController.php**

```
    public function login(){

     $userData = [
        'email' => request('email'),
        'password' => request('password'),
    ];

    if(Auth::attempt($userData, true)){
        return 'Success';
    } else {
        return 'Fail';
    }
}
```

**Config/Auth.php** - I use the player model so I needed to change the model here

```
    'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Player::class,
    ],
```

Thank you very much for taking time to my problem, I can give you more details if it helps you and have a nice day full of code :)

P.S. I really don't know why my "Hello" doesn't appear on this topic =( But Hello anyway :D

Comment: Can you try `auth->guard()->attempt()`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. For information i use only email and password to login

Comment: I modified my controller, more readable but it always returns 'Fail' on my if statement.

Comment: everything seems normal, I can't figure out too.. May I ask, why you can say just  `make:auth`. İt's very easy